Having Business Key in Kimball style fact tables
Many Kimball style star schema articles suggest that not to have a BK in Fact tables, the grain/uniqueness of Fact tables are supposed to be maintained by the combined SKs from its Dimension tables.
Which really confuse me because in practice I saw many fact tables have a stand alone key to solely identify each records(grain) in the table. And I think it totally makes sense, SKs from dimensions are not sufficient to represent the grain in most cases, for a simple example --
A fact transaction table to represent business process "Customer buying product"
In this fact table it will have "SK_Customer", "SK_Product" and other fields like "Time of Purchase" etc
For this simple process only these two SKs are required. However, I don't think they are enough to represent the grain. So most likely there will be a BK of the fact table like "TransactionNo" or similar to identify its grain
So am I interpret Kimball approach wrong?

Why, in your example, don't you have a transactions dimension table? Then you can use that table's surrogate key.

Fact tables can contain degenerate dimensions - where there is only a single attribute for a dimension. Instead of creating a dimension table to hold this one attribute, the attribute is held in the fact table as a degenerate dimension. Attributes like "Transaction Number" or "Order Number" are classic examples of degenerate dimensions. https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/degenerate-dimension/

@NickW Thanks! I think this is the answer I am after. It is quite confusing due to many systems made the "TransactionNo" unique which serves exactly same as the Business Key of the transaction table.
